# Java program delays whitespace strings from printing to console

Tags: java, string

This is a problem I've encountered several times, and always wondered why.

For my code below as an example, if a string of whitespace is entered, the method will not print. However, after the next input with a value string containing characters, it will print all the whitespace strings and the valid character containing string. Why is this delayed and stored in memory?

Example for the code below:
Enter "  " returns nothing.
Enter "  " returns nothing.
Enter "SwiggitySwooty" returns "  " \n "  " \n "SwiggitySwooty"
Explaination: The whitespace containing strings are delayed until a valid character string is entered.

Extra info: I use intellij, also happens when not sending the string to a method. I've also had this happen during a while(input.hasNext()) statement, in which I try to catch an invalid input as a string, when I want to take an integer. If I enter 'n' amount of legitimate integers, and then a string, it would print out my "please enter an integer" that 'n' amount of times like in this code.

Lastly, if anyone thinks of a better title for this, let me know so I can change it for more exposure for those with similar questions. Thank you.

Let me know if you guys need anything else!

```
/**
 * Created by JacobHein on 4/19/15.
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FizzString {
/*TODO
* Given a string str, if the string starts with "f" return "Fizz". 
If the string ends
* with "b" return "Buzz". If both the "f" and "b" conditions are true, return
* "FizzBuzz". In all other cases, return the string unchanged. */
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

  while(input.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(fizzString(input.nextLine()));
  }
}
public static String fizzString(String str) {
  String result=str;
  int l=str.length();
  if (str.charAt(0)=='f'||str.charAt(l-1)=='b') {
    result="";
    if (l>0) {
      if (str.charAt(0)=='f') {
        result="Fizz";
      }
      if (str.charAt(0)=='b') {
        result="Buzz";
      }
      if (l>1) {
      /*technique: continue the process if l>1 (within l>0 if statement),
      prevents breaking the program.*/
        if (str.charAt(l-1)=='b') {
          result="Buzz";
        }
        if (str.charAt(0)=='f'&&str.charAt(l-1)=='b') {
          result="FizzBuzz";
        }
      }/*end l>1*/
    }/*end l>0*/
  }/*end charAt if*/
  return result;
 }
 }
```

Comment: `input.hasNext()` returns if there is a valid token in the stream. A whitespace is not a valid *token*, so it "waits" until you enter one. Then you're loop and `input.nextLine()` will read every *line*.

Comment: This also holds true if I were to assign input.nextLine() to a String variable?

Comment: You are actually assigning `input.nextLine()` to the `String` variable that is passed as parameter to the method `fizzString`

Comment: Well, you should decide what you want: do want to read and evaluate every line instantly? If yes, then use `while(input.hasNextLine())`. Or do you want to read only *real* tokens and not whitespaces, then use `System.out.println(fizzString(input.next()));`.

Comment: Thank you Tom, that did indeed resolve that. Thank you. I'll try to see if I can find more information on this so I can prevent it in other cases. I'm usually afraid of this when submitting to UVAonline, which is why the curiosity. Now I know! :)

Comment: Also, leave an answer so I can credit you Tom.

Comment: @JacobHein No need to credit me, thank you :). If the current answer aren't what your looking for, then you could write an answer yourself by explain what you did and why you did that. Then you can accept it (but this "feature" can be looked to a certain time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the behavior of the Scanner class:

```
The next and hasNext methods and their primitive-type companion methods
(such as nextInt and hasNextInt) first skip any input that matches the
delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token. Both 
hasNext and next methods may block waiting for further input. Whether a 
hasNext method blocks has no connection to whether or not its 
associated next method will block.
```

Internally, the `Scanner` class is performing the following operation:

```
    while (!sourceClosed) {
        if (hasTokenInBuffer())
            return revertState(true);
        readInput();
    }
```

The method `hasTokenInBuffer()` skips all the delimiter tokens (by default is `\p{javaWhitespace}+`), so only when the class found a non-delimiter token, it returns true in the `hasNext()` method.

For example, if you type this content: "\n\n\n5\n" and then execute `nextInt()` method, you'll obtain a result of `5`, because Scanner automatically skips all the return line characters.

If you want to find some string into a line, try with the method `java.util.Scanner.findInLine` instead of `nextLine()`.

Use the patterns: `^f(.)*` to look for every line that starts with a `f` character and the pattern `(.)*b$` to look for every line that ends with a `b` character.

Comment: I guess it is much easier to use `#next()`, than `#findInLine()`.

Comment: Maybe, it depends on you :). However, I've tried to explain why `hasNext()` doesn't return until Scanner finds a non-delimiter character.

Comment: Thank you very much! You all really helped me out there. A view college assignments I've written have had this problem (Even though the valid inputs aren't necessary, I try to make it a habit). If you can, explain that ^f(.)* for me? My program works completely fine, however I think you're statement there could make it easier? Thank you!

Comment: Of course you do! The token `^` indicates that the following characters **must** be present **at the beginning** of the string. The rest of the pattern matches any `f` plus any number of characters: `(.)*` zero or more characters of any type

Comment: Thank you again. I have used this before for replaceAll(".*[^a-b].*"," "); statements. however I still don't see where I can use this for this code, as I'm not replacing anything. I'll figure it out though. Thank you!

Comment: Well, instead of using `str.charAt(0)=='f'` you can use `^f(.)*`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String inputLine = "";
    do {
        inputLine = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println(fizzString(inputLine));
        System.out.println("");
    } while (inputLine.length() > 0);

    System.out.println("Goodbye");
}

public static String fizzString(String str) {
    // Given a string
    // If both the "f" and "b" conditions are true, return FizzBuzz
    if (str.startsWith("f") && str.endsWith("b")) {
        return "FizzBuzz";
    }

    // If the string starts with "f" return "Fizz".
    if (str.startsWith("f")) {
        return "Fizz";
    }

    // If the string ends with "b" return "Buzz".
    if (str.endsWith("b")) {
        return "Buzz";
    }

    // In all other cases, return the string unchanged.
    return str;
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: That isn't exactly what I was looking for. The reason why it does that is what I was looking for. Resolved by not using .nextLine() and use .next()

Comment: I appreciate your response. Although not what I was looking for, you did remind me of the str.endsWith and .beginsWith methods. +1.